# I'm trying to create a discord.js command that grabs a line from a json file and then sends it in a users DM

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So i have a discord bot that generates keys, which you can redeem by a command. I want a command that grabs a line from a keys.txt and dms the sender of the command.

I have tried doing it myself, without any luck. I'm not that familiar with javascript so it's hard for me.

I don't have any code yet.

I expect it to DM the sender of the command the key that it grabbed from the keys.json

Comment: Is it a keys.json or keys.txt file?

Comment: It is keys.txt.

Answer (score 1):

**Reading and handling the file...**

```js
const fs = require('fs');  // Included in Node.js

const keysPath = './keys.txt'; // Change to the relative path of the txt file

try {
  // The next line reads the file and returns an array containing each line
  const keys = fs.readFileSync(keysPath).replace(/\r/g, '').split(/\n/);
} catch(err) {
  console.error(err);
}
```

**Sending and handling a key...**

```js
message.author.send(`Here's your key: ||${keys[0]}||`)
  .then(() => {
    keys.splice(0, 1); // Removes the first key that was just given out

    try {
      fs.writeFileSync(keys.join('\n')); // Puts the updated 'keys' array back into the file
    } catch(err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  })
  .catch(console.error);
```

Answer (score 0):

### Get a line from a txt file

For this you need "line-reader". Install it with `npm i line-reader`.

```
const lineReader = require("line-reader")

lineReader.eachLine("path/to/file.txt", (line) => {

 // This will be executed for each line in the file

})
```

### Send a direct message to a user who executed a command

```
// client is your Discord.Client()

client.on("message", (message) => {

 if (message.content === "YOUR_COMMAND") {

  message.author.send("YOUR_MESSAGE")

 }

})
```

### Full code

```
const lineReader = require("line-reader")

var keys = []

lineReader.eachLine("path/to/file.txt", (line) => {

 keys.push(line)

})

client.on("message", (message) => {

 if (message.content === "YOUR_COMMAND") {

  message.author.send("Key: " + keys[0]) // This will send the user the first key/line in the list.

 }

})
```

Comment: So like this?                                                                                                               <blink>  const lineReader = require("line-reader")

var keys = []

lineReader.eachLine("/keys.txt", (line) => {

 keys.push(line)

})

client.on("message", (message) => {

    if(command == "grabkey") {

  message.author.send("Key: " + keys[0]) // This will send the user the first code in the list.

 }

}) </blink>

Comment: Yeah.. but you have to use `===` and not `==` and `if (command ...` is not working, it's `message.content`. Or you have created a variable thats named `command`, then its ok.

Comment: I have created a variable that's named command for the ease, There is no errors, but it seems like the command isn't running. Could you add me on discord, and we could figure it out from there?